# Erro ao requisitar API

Tags: java, api, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Estou recebendo um erro, possivelmente de CORS, ao fazer um GET para uma API, sendo que é uma API de terceiros e eu não tenho como libera o CORS do lado do servidor:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/time/id/17886329/1": Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Estou consumindo uma API usando RestTemplate da seguinte maneira:

```
public class FamiliabomdebolaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FamiliabomdebolaApplication.class, args);


        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

        UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("https").host("api.cartolafc.globo.com")
                .path("time/id/17886329/1")
                // .queryParam("fields", "all")
                .build();

        ResponseEntity<Time> entity = template.getForEntity(uri.toUriString(), Time.class);

        System.out.println(entity.getBody().getEsquema_id());

    }

}
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Ouvi falar algo sobre usar proxy, mas não sei como implementar isso no Java/Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas [adicione um User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238715/how-to-set-an-accept-header-on-spring-resttemplate-request) na requisição que ela passará a funcionar.

```
private static HttpHeaders createHttpHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.26.2");
    return headers;
}

private static void fazerRequest() {
    UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("https").host("api.cartolafc.globo.com")
                                            .path("time/id/17886329/1")
                                            // .queryParam("fields", "all")
                                            .build();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        System.out.println("Result - status ("+ response.getStatusCode() + ") has body: " + response.hasBody());
    }
    catch (Exception eek) {
        System.out.println("** Exception: "+ eek.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Se você fizer o teste no postman verá que o endpoint não aceita requisições sem um user-agent o que acaba fazendo com que o servidor recuse sua requisição.

Comment: Perfeito, Emerson. Muito obrigado!